# Calling an instance method in a .razor page from JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

My main goal is to call a C# method whenever the user scrolls to the bottom of my page.
I searched for a solution using blazor alone, but couldn't find one.

Therefore, I'm using jQuery to register the scroll event and then I'm using JSInvokable to call the C# Method.

jQuery code:

```
<script>
    //Used to register scroll event.
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('Blazor-Example', 'OnScroll');
        }
    });
</script>
```

.Net code (in the .razor page):

```
@code {
  //This is called from jquery
  [JSInvokable("OnScroll")]
  public static void OnScroll()
  {
    //TODO: How to get hold of the razor component instance?
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I want to call an instance method in my .razor page, not a static one.

In other words: How can I get the instance of the razor page from JavaScript?

I tried using a static instance of the type `__generated__[Name_of_the_razor_page]` that is set during OnInitialized(), but then my code just wouldn't compile with no errors shown.

If it is not possible to get the instance of a razor component, is there another way to register my scroll event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send a `DotNetObjectReference` to your javascript and use this reference to invoke your callback :

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime
...
@code {
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
     jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("scroll.init", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this))
  }
  //This is called from jquery
  [JSInvokable("OnScroll")]
  public void OnScroll()
  {
    //TODO: How to get hold of the razor component instance?
  }
}
```

```js
window.scroll = {
   init: dotnetHelper => {
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            dotnetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('OnScroll')
               .then(_ => { });
        }
    })     
   }
};
```

Comment: Had to `@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime` into the razor page and of course remove the `static` from my method. Works great, thanks!